# Проверка неверного ввода в django

Tags: python, django

Как сделать проверку, чтобы при указывании часов бронирования в using_time '0' выходила ошибка и просила повторить указать часы еще раз?

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    computer_club = models.ForeignKey('clubs.Club', models.CASCADE, related_name='club_reservation', null=True)
    seats = models.ForeignKey('clubs.Table', models.CASCADE, related_name='seats_reservation', null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner_reservation', null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField('Введите время бронирования')
    time1 = models.DateTimeField('Время окончания бронирования', blank=True)
    using_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Введите на сколько часов вы садитесь')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Бронирование'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Бронирование'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.computer_club } {self.seats } {self.time } {self.using_time } {self.time1 } {self.owner }'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time = self.time
        time += timedelta(hours=self.using_time)
        self.time1 = time
        super(Reservation, self).save()

    def reservation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
          if self.using_time == 0:
            print('Ошибка!')
            continue
          else:
            print('Бронь успешна')
            break
    reservation(using_time)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/

Comment: Но возможно там есть `min_value` или что то подобное, можете посмотреть исходники, найти поле и узнать. Но валидаторы точно сработают

Comment: ну или прописывайте в форме условия

Comment: @Za Ars благодарствую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На уровне моделей, да и на уровне форм можно использовать `MinLengthValidator`. Просто у поля using_time укажите свойство `validators` (оно является списком). Ну это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator


class Reservation(models.Model):
    ...
    using_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Введите на сколько часов вы садитесь',validators=[MinLengthValidator(1,message='Меньше 1 нельзя!')])
```

Первый аргумент этого класса - это минимально допустимое значение для вашего поля, второй аргумент `message` - текст ошибки, который выведется, если в поле введут некорректно значение, в вашем случае некорректно значение - числа, которые меньше 1. Еще можно воспользоваться методам clean, опять же у модели и у формы. Или сделать метод clean_using_time. Можете прочитать поподробнее:

https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/forms/validation.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/

Comment: спасибо но ответ был чуточку иным

Comment: А ну да, я MinValueValidator перепутал с MinLengthValidator, извиняюсь.

Answer (score 0):

```
using_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Введите на сколько часов вы садитесь', validators=[MinValueValidator(1,message='Меньше 1 нельзя!'),MaxValueValidator(10,message='Больше 10 нельзя!')])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]